# Hot to use custom SQL functions in the WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite, knex.js

I'm trying to make a where clause with custom functions applied to the columns using Knex.js.

Suppose I have a table named `tableName` with columns named `col1, col2, col3` and a function `f` that receives as parameter something that is the same type of the things that are in `col1` and `col2`.

I also have two variables named `var1` and `var2` (defined beforehand) that are the same type of the thing returned by `f`. I tried some ways.

Example 1:

```
let rows = knexClient("tableName").whereRaw('f(?) <= ${var1} AND f(?) >= ${var2}', [col1, col2]).then((rows) => {
  for (row of rows) {
    console.log('${row["col1"]} ${row["col2"]} ${row["col3"]}');
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});
```

This gives the following error:

```
ReferenceError: col1 is not defined.
```

Example 2:

```
let rows = knexClient("tableName").whereRaw("f(col1) <= ? AND f(col2) >= ?", [var1, var2]).then((rows) => {
  for (row of rows) {
    console.log('${row["col1"]} ${row["col2"]} ${row["col3"]}');
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});
```

This gives the following error:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: col1] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
```

What is the right way to do it? I have searched around and saw some people doing things similar to my first try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596091/how-to-apply-a-function-on-a-value-of-a-where-clause-using-knex). But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind column names dynamically (i.e. using `?` placeholders), that only works for values.

The following:

```
var var1 = 10, var2 = 20;

knex("tableName")
    .whereRaw("f(col1) <= ?", var1)
    .whereRaw("f(col2) => ?", var2)
    .select();
```

results in generated SQL like this:

```
select
  *
from
  tableName
where
  f(col1) <= 10
  and f(col2) => 20
```

If you have variables that contain the target column names, you need to format them in yourself:

```
var col1 = "some_col", col2 = "other_col";
var var1 = 10, var2 = 20;

knex("tableName")
    .whereRaw(`f(${col1}) <= ?`, var1)
    .whereRaw(`f(${col2}) => ?`, var2)
    .select();
```

which produces

```
select
  *
from
  tableName
where
  f(some_col) <= 10
  and f(other_col) => 20
```

Comment: Thanks! My case is the first one that you mentioned. Now it's producing the right query but I'm getting the error
[Error: select * from `tableName` where f(col1) <= var1 and f(col2) >= var2 - SQLITE_ERROR: no such function: f] {
      errno: 1,
      code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
  }

Comment: Does f need to be set somewhere inside the knex query to be used ?

Comment: @python123 I was under the impression that `f` was a function that *you had defined in SQLite*. If that is not the case, then of course you need to define that function first. You can't call Javascript functions from your SQL query.

Comment: I see. What is the syntax to define a custom function using Knex.js ? I can't find the docs about it

Comment: @python123 You can't define a custom function through Knex.js. All that Knex does is generate an SQL string, and send that SQL string to a DB engine (such as SQLite) for execution. These things are completely separate. SQLite supports [creating custom functions](https://www.sqlite.org/appfunc.html) but there is no way to do that dynamically from Node.js. You would either have to [load an extension](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Extensions), which requires writing C and compiling it, or replace the `f` with an SQL expression - depending on what `f` does, this might be possible.

Comment: I see, thanks. In my case f converts a date to a string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". col1 and col2 contain dates. Is there some way to contour the use of this function in SQL ?

Comment: @python123 SQLite has a [comprehensive list of date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you can use them. You don't need your custom `f`. You will probably need `strftime()` and 15 minutes of reading the documentation and experimenting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give a look. I will also choose your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @python123 I'd recommend using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) as a tool to experiment with the SQL, and when you have figured it out, you will know what expression to use in `.whereRaw()`.

Comment: Also, if your date columns columns in SQLIte are formatted as ISO dates (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:nn:ss`) then you don't need a function at all. You can directly compare them against values formatted in the same way. `.where('somedate', '>=', var1)`. This would improve query performance considerably. If your date columns in SQLIte are *not* formatted this way, you should very strongly consider converting them. Every other date format is inferior.

Comment: @python123 ...and while you're at it, you should make sure that all dates in your database are strictly UTC. Convert them to UTC before storing them, and only convert them to local dates when displaying them to users.

Comment: Thanks, @Tomalak, you gave a great introduction for a beginner like me working with databases

Comment: @python123 One thing to know about SQLite is that there is no DATE/DATETIME datatype. SQLite accepts those keywords, but date values are always saved as strings (TEXT). That's why it's important to pick the right date format when you save data to your tables, and to stick to that format.

Comment: Yes, @Tomalak. I'm currently using a function to correct the time zone offset and then I store everything as strings in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM;SS" (in the database and in my variables). It works well and now I can query just using .where('somedate', '>=', var1), as you suggested